# Explicitly overwriting the dependency of a dependency in pip

Tags: python, pip, dependency-management

My module's `setup.py` specifies `packageA>=1.0.0`.
`packageA`, however, has dependency `packageB` with a bug. There is a fix for the bug, and I can specify it as requirement like so to explicitly install it: `"packageB @ git+https://github.com/user/packageB.git@fix-branch"`. Installing my module in editable mode works.

However, when I run one of my module's `console_scripts` I get errors of `packageA` complaining about incompatibility with the `packageB` fork:

> pkg_resources.ContextualVersionConflict: (packageB 0.1.dev1004+g2c00cc8 (/Users/johannes/Library/Python/3.7/lib/python/site-packages), Requirement.parse('packageB>=x.xx.x'), {'packageA'})

How can I overwrite the dependency of a dependency to use a particular git object/branch/commit?